# Squircle реализация на css/js

Tags: css

Дизайнер хочет на сайте все скругления(картинок и кнопок) реализовать с помощью squircle, что это можно прочитать [тут](https://ux.pub/zakruglennye-ugly-v-ekosisteme-apple-superellips/)

Я пока нашла два варианта:

1. на чистом css в помощью before и after, но этот вариант подходит только для элементов со сплошной заливкой цветом [пример](https://codepen.io/rogie/pen/alBcH);

   ```
    <p class="codepen" data-height="265" data-theme-id="light" data-default-tab="css,result" data-user="rogie" data-slug-hash="alBcH" style="height: 265px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" data-pen-title="CSS Squircle">
   ```

   See the Pen 
   [CSS Squircle](https://codepen.io/rogie/pen/alBcH) by Rogie ([@rogie](https://codepen.io/rogie))
   on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).
2. с помощью Squircley.js он позволяет менять параметры svg, но тогда нужно загружать картинки только в формате svg [пример](https://www.cssscript.com/squircle-generator/);
3. с помощью houdini, но у него очень плохая поддержка [пример](https://github.com/PavelLaptev/squircle-houdini-css);

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой? В идеале нужно найти универсальный способ и для картинок(без привязки к формату) и для элементов с заливкой цветом.